# Pass php value with ajax with ajax post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm using an ajax script to post a value to a PHP file.
I'm not able to pass the variable.

My variable is declared in PHP and I would like to pass it with ajax.

Here is the variable and my button:

```
<?php $employee_id= '3'; ?>    
<input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" id="delete-btn">
```

This is the Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#delete-btn").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php", // 
                data: {id: '$employee_id'},
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#thanks").html(msg)  
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is the PHP code where I want to receive the value:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$emp_id = strip_tags($_POST['id']); 

echo $emp_id;

$query = "DELETE FROM `employee` WHERE id='$emp_id'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error()); 

echo 'You successfully deleted the user.';}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong around the data...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because your variable is in php but you are not using php to attach your variable to your ajax, try wrapping your variable in php tags and then make sure you use 'echo' to print the value of your variable into javascript.

```
data: {id: <?php echo '$employee_id'?>},
```

Your javascript code, as far as the client will see, will end up looking like this for them:

```
data: {id: '3'},
```

They won't see the php code, they will just see the end result as their javascript.

Comment: Thank this is so simple haha The only thing I didn't try. Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You need PHP tags around your variables:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#delete-btn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php", // 
            data: {id: <?php echo '$employee_id'; ?> }, // <---
            success: function(msg){
                $("#thanks").html(msg)  
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```